# How can I avoid that In memoir class when a chapter starts the page style is lost as happens in my MWE. I want to have footers in every page

Tags: memoir

```
\documentclass[a4paper, article openright, twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{Foot}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{Foot}{\thepage}

\makechapterstyle{mychap}{
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\bfseries \fontsize{14}{10.8}}
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}{\chaptitlefont{}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont{}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\thechapter\quad}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{--\quad}
    \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
    \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\bigskip}
    \setlength\beforechapskip{4.5ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}
    }
%
\begin{document}
%
\chapterstyle{mychap}%\sectionstyle{body}
%
\pagestyle{mystyle}
%
\chapter{CHAP 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{SEC1}
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{CHAP 2}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `article` and  `openright` options are different options and you have to seperate them by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class uses the `chapter` page style on initial chapter pages. This is an alias for the `plain` page style, so we first need to make it a page style on its own and then define its features.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{Foot}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{Foot}{\thepage}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{mystyle}

\makechapterstyle{mychap}{
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\bfseries \fontsize{14}{10.8}}
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}{\chaptitlefont{}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont{}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\thechapter\quad}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{--\quad}
    \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
    \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\bigskip}
    \setlength\beforechapskip{4.5ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}
    }

\chapterstyle{mychap}
%\sectionstyle{body}
\pagestyle{mystyle}


\begin{document}

\chapter{CHAP 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{SEC1}
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{CHAP 2}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Since you don't have headers, it would be perhaps simpler to do

```
\copypagestyle{chapter}{mystyle}
```

so no further adjustment would be needed. However, I believe it's better to keep them separate.

Declarations of the global chapter and page styles should go in the document preamble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try redefining the `plain` pagestyle like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, article, openright, twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{Foot}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{Foot}{\thepage}

\makechapterstyle{mychap}{
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\bfseries \fontsize{14}{10.8}}
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}{\chaptitlefont{}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont{}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\thechapter\quad}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{--\quad}
    \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
    \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\bigskip}
    \setlength\beforechapskip{4.5ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}
    }
%
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{Foot}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{Foot}{\thepage}

\begin{document}
%
\chapterstyle{mychap}%\sectionstyle{body}
%
\pagestyle{mystyle}
%
\chapter{CHAP 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{SEC1}
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{CHAP 2}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

The "problem" in your example is that a chapter redefines the page style to `plain` for the current page... So, if you don't want this behavior you have to redefine it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Welcome @Richard ... Happy TeXing